# How to compare string which has dynamic value

Tags: c#, string

I have this string.
string str = "Connecting to remote server 104.255.152.68 failed"

I want to compare this whole string ignoring "104.255.152.68", something like this - "Connecting to remote server {} failed". if this satisfied will return true.

how to do it ?

Comment: Take a look at [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-6.0). The pattern could look like this `Connecting to remote server [0-9\.]* failed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `Regex.IsMatch` to find whether a given string contains this string. Feel free to alter the regular expression as you wish!

Ex:

```
string str = "Connecting to remote server 104.255.152.68 failed";
string pattern = @"^(Connecting to remote server ).*( failed)$"; 
// This is a regex that will match exactly that string. Instead of .* you may also use [0-9\.]+ 
// If you remove ^ and $ symbol, then the error string can be searched in a subpart. Including those makes the string exactly equal.
bool errorFound = Regex.IsMatch(str, pattern);
```

Reference for [IsMatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch?view=net-6.0).

Answer (score 1):

I love regular expressions, but learning to use them can be very steep. Here's a simple alternative:

```cs
if (s.StartsWith("Connecting to remote server ") && s.EndsWith(" failed"))
{
    ...
}
```

It's a little more forgiving than the RegEx version, since it will also allow a servername, or in fact any string in between the two parts.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create another string that holds a substring of "Connecting to remote server 104.255.152.68 failed"

In this case, the substring would go from index 0 to 27.

2. Create a new string that holds the substring you created + " {} failed".

Now you have a string that would look like "Connecting to remote server {} failed"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).